# How do I use Java to launch a local HTML page that uses Javascript to load a local json file and display its contents?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a java application that reports on the up/down status of several websites and creates a .json file with the data. I have an HTML page that uses javascript to take a .json file and display a nice little grid with red or green lights telling you if a website is up or down. I have *no idea* how to make the java app tell the html page exactly what the .json file is named (i create a new timestamped .json file every app run). Is there any way to pass a parameter or something to the HTML page on load (currently using `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("file://blah");`), or am I stuck to overwriting my .json file every time I run the app?

Comment: It may be easier than you think to have your Java application display a UI showing the status of the websites.  Do you need this to be viewable in a browser?

Comment: It would be preferable, yes - I was told to do it in a browser, and the project-assigner is not currently in the office.

Comment: Can your Java program just always name the latest file something like up-down-status-latest.json and rename the older files to something else? This way you could rename the file and keep it instead of overwriting it every time.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a query parameter? Like `file://blah.html?json=foo.json` Or a fragment: `file://blah.html#foo.json`.

Comment: I've tried that but the URI doesn't seem to populate it in the browser  - I just end up with my index.html page and no params appended

Comment: Very strange. Both versions worked for me when I tried, my default browser is Chrome on OS X. Java 6 on same platform. Might be browser-specific?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tiny local server and register the url /json to any file you want:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class main {
    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new IndexHandler());
        server.createContext("/json", new JsonHandler());
        server.start();
    }

    static class IndexHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            String response = readFile("index.html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
    static class JsonHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            String response = readFile("whatEverJsonYouWant.json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the JS can be changed to fetch /json